# php.ini file - openssl

Tags: openssl, php

in php.ini file

there is a line like that

```
 extension=php_openssl.dll
```

which define OpenSSL

but there is one more line which is header of this extension something like that

[PHPOpenSSL]

what was it ? what was this[text] ty

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The

> extension=php_openssl.dll

Tells PHP to load that DLL.

The

> [PHPOpenSSL]

line defines parameters specific to that library. Specifically, words inside of [brackets] define section headers, and php.ini organizes extensions into sections.

Answer (score 3):

In an .ini file `[PHPOpenSSL]` defines a section. Everything under that section can be parsed and/or accessed separately from the rest. Look at the wiki article for INI http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/INI_file

> Sections:
>   Properties may be grouped into arbitrarily named sections. The section name appears on a line by itself, in square brackets ([ and ]). All properties after the section declaration are associated with that section. There is no explicit "end of section" delimiter; sections end at the next section declaration, or the end of the file. Sections may not be nested.

A crude example would be something like:

```
[MySection]
foo = 1
bar = 2
```

And that could be accessed with (depending on the implementation):

```
$config->MySection->foo;
```

According to http://php.net/manual/en/openssl.configuration.php there are no configuration options for the OpenSSL section.

Answer (score 1):

The OpenSSL extension has no configuration directives defined in php.ini.

The word you're looking for does not exist.